# change mysqli check exit and insert into pdo statement

Tags: mysqli, pdo

i want to change my mysqli check exist and insert into pdo.. my statement look like below:

```
 <?php

$addSearch = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $search);


if ($CheckMusic = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE term='$addSearch'")) {

    $CheckRow = mysqli_fetch_array($CheckMusic);

    $CheckId = $CheckRow['id'];

    $CheckCnt = $CheckMusic->num_rows;

    $CheckMusic->close();

} else {

    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

$Now = strtotime("now");


$addSearch = $mysqli->escape_string($addSearch);


if ($CheckCnt < 1) {


    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO search (term, datetime) VALUES('$addSearch','$Now') ") or die(mysqli_error());

} else {

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE search SET datetime='$Now' WHERE id='$CheckId'") or die(mysqli_error());
}


?>
```

hope someone can help with sample if can ;q thanks for your advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $addSearch = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $search);
    $CheckMusic = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE term='$addSearch'");
    $Now = strtotime("now");
    if($CheckMusic->num_rows == 0){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO search (term, datetime) VALUES('$addSearch','$Now') ") or die(mysqli_error());
    }else{
        $CheckRow = mysqli_fetch_array($CheckMusic);
        $CheckId = $CheckRow['id'];
        $addSearch = $mysqli->escape_string($addSearch);
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE search SET datetime='$Now' WHERE id='$CheckId'") or die(mysqli_error());
    }
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: i am so sorry..might be my question not clear. Thanks for that sample. can you give samples for PDO statement?

Comment: cant you give me a samples for PDO statement? this is my question..thanks you so much sir.

Comment: Well,I can give you here the idea but not 100% complete solution. 
for your reference, you can check this link http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php